# Whats the different about try: and def?

Tags: python

I'm trying to Open a file as text, choosing the file via `str(raw_input`, but it doesn't work with `def main():`.

My second script, with normal (No threading), is using `try:`. The threading one not opening the email.
Here is a link to the scripts in ghostbin:

[Normal Script Without Threading](https://ghostbin.com/paste/6ry2w) and [Multithread Script](https://ghostbin.com/paste/83o3k) ,

The Normal Script Without Threading

```
try:
    filelist = str(raw_input("[+] Enter Mailist File: "))
    loglive = open('live.txt','a')
    logdie = open('die.txt','a')
    logun = open('uncheck.txt','a')
except Exception as Err:
    print("ERROR : File List Not Found!")
    sys.exit()
list = open(filelist, "r")
while True:
    email = list.readline().replace("\n","")
    if not email:
        break
```

Multithread Script

```
def main():
    start_time = time.time()
    tanya = str(raw_input("[+] Enter Mailist File: "))
    mailist = open(tanya, 'r')
    while True:
        email = mailist.readline().replace("\n","")
        if not email:
            break
    s = requests.session()
```

Comment: What do you mean with "StackOverflow really don't nice with python"? I edited your question by putting the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the `main` function for it to be executed. At the end of your file, add:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The reason for this can be found here: [What does if __name__ == "__main__": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)